# What is correct path to WP_CLI library to require_once?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-cli

I am trying use `require_once ('...');` to create `class extended WP_CLI_Command`. I have installed `wp-cli.phar` by:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
```

after

```
php wp-cli.phar --info

OS: Linux 5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 29 16:12:28 UTC 2019 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php7.2
PHP version:    7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
php.ini used:   /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /var/www/html/wcexport/wp-content/plugins/export-csv
WP-CLI packages dir:    
WP-CLI global config:   /home/tomasz/.wp-cli/config.yml
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 2.2.0



class Hello_World_Command extends WP_CLI_Command {
    public function __invoke(){
        WP_CLI::success('Hello World');
    }
}
WP_CLI::add_command('hello', 'Hello_World_Command');
```

And I'd like to use as:

`wp hello` in command line

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? What does your code do, and what would you like it to do that it doesn't? Are you getting error messages? Etc. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Probably you have to know something avout wp_cli. It is Command Line Interfade helps interact with visual elements to execute technical commands. This code should add new command 'hello'. After type 'wp hello' shows 'hello'. It is only example. The main problem is how to append or use WP_CLI library to may use wp_cli classes. 
https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/wp-cli-beginners-guide/
https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/quick-start/
https://www.dreamhost.com/wordpress/guide-to-wp-cli/